# canScroll not getting called on custom ViewPager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a really crazy problem.

I want to prevent my custom `ViewPager` from scrolling with overriding the `canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y)` method.

It works very well if I use my `ProductsFragment`. Even if I use it multiple times in the same `ViewPager` it works perfectly.

The problem is now, if I use another Fragment `canScroll` will not trigger on that specific Fragment.
But I want different Fragments in my App :D

ViewPager:

```
public class LockableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public LockableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    Log.i("tag","id: "+getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId()));

    return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class AppointmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public AppointmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 2:
            return new ProductsFragment(); //this works
        case 3:
            return new ProductsFragment(); //this works
        case 1:
            return new InfoFragment(); //this works Not
        case 0:
            return new ScheduleFragment(); //this works Not
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

ProductsFragment:

```
public class ProductsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);


    ProductsRecycleAdapter adapter=new ProductsRecycleAdapter(getDummyData(), new ProductsRecycleAdapter.ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void addToCart(int position) {
            Log.i("log","addToCart: "+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void clicked(int position) {
            Log.i("log","clicked: "+position);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_products_recycle);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}
```

ScheduleFragment:

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);


    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}
```

}

The output on the LogCat should be for example:

```
    tag: id: act_appointment_pager
    tag: id: fragment_products
    tag: id: frag_products_recycle
    tag: id: act_appointment_pager
    tag: id: fragment_products
    tag: id: frag_products_recycle
    tag: id: act_appointment_pager
    tag: id: fragment_products
    tag: id: frag_products_recycle
```

But i get no output for other fragments than the `ProductsFragment`.

And yes, the views have IDs.

Isn't that weird?^^

I hope you can point me into the right direction.

Edit:
I forgot the entry point...

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment);

    setupToolbar();

    AppointmentPagerAdapter adapter=new AppointmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    LockableViewPager pager= (LockableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.act_appointment_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out and maybe someone wants to know how.

The setup is correct.
If the fragment has no scrolling content, the method `canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y)` will not trigger.

I added some scrolling content and now it works.

But if there is a scolling content and a non-scrolling content in the fragment, the method only triggers on the scrolling content.

So it seems that if you swipe at a non-scrolling content, the method is simply ignored.

Additionally you should give each view in the layout an ID.

I think the things being said here are not documented, but correct me if I'm wrong about this.